# PHP Getting values from JSON array in php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to set up a small weather application and I need to get the main weather condition for tomorrow. I have searched StackOverflow for hours and don't seem to get it to work.

```
    {"cod":"200","message":0.0026,"city":{"id":3413829,"name":"Reykjavik","coord":           
    {"lon":-21.895411,"lat":64.135483},"country":"IS","population":0,"sys":
    {"population":0}},"cnt":1,"list":[{"dt":1404349200,"temp":
    {"day":281.58,"min":281.18,"max":283.73,"night":283.73,"eve":281.38,"morn":282.15},"pressure":971.54,"humidity":100
```

but here's the part i'm looking for which is in an array.

```
    ,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":2.52,"deg":308,"clouds":92,"rain":2.5}]}
```

Here's the php:

```
    $json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Reykjavik&cnt=1&mode=json");
    $jsonData = json_decode($json_string, true);
    $vedur = $jsonData["weather"]["main"];
    echo "Það er ".$vedur . "í Reykjavík";
```

Comment: The first JSON string you sent isnt valid you still need `}]}` at the end

Comment: Do you get an error, "don't seem to get it to work" doesn't really help us understand the problem. Have you dumped the `$jsonData` array to see what it looks like?

Comment: This is the JSON i'm getting from the server, would that be causing my problems?

Comment: No I just get a blank page when I try to run it. And no, I'm kind of a beginner with JSON so I don't know a lot of techniques

Comment: use `$vedur = $jsonData['list'][0]["weather"][0]["main"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the list array first to get (I guess) all days, then loop over the items in there to display the weather for each day:

```
foreach ($jsonData['list'] AS $item) {
    foreach ($item['weather'] AS $weather) {
        var_dump($item['weather']); 
    }
}
```

or with your example:

```
foreach ($jsonData['list'] AS $item) { 
    foreach ($item['weather'] AS $weather) {
        echo "Það er ".$weather['main'] . "í Reykjavík";
    }
}
```

Comment: That just returns "Það er í Reykjavík", but I think I need to use a foreach loop, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Could be this, you have written:

```
$jsonData["weather"]["main"][;
```

With an extra square bracket shoud be:

```
$jsonData["weather"]["main"];
```

Comment: Then the echo text appears, but not the JSON value

Comment: Try: `$jsonData->list[0]->weather[0]->main`

Comment: That returns the same text, maybe it needs quotes?

Comment: This: `$weather = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Reykjavik&cnt=1&mode=json");
$item = json_decode($weather);

echo "Það er ". $item->list[0]->weather[0]->main  . "í Reykjavík";` works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 $json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Reykjavik&cnt=1&mode=json");
 $jsonData = json_decode($json_string, true);
 $vedur = $jsonData['list'][0]['weather'][0]['main'];
 echo "Það er ".$vedur . "í Reykjavík";
```